# ActionBar - PullToRefresh for PullBottom and PullTop

Tags: android, pull-to-refresh

I've checked out the famous ActionBar-PullToRefresh by ChrisBanes' and it has been clearly stated that he doesn't want to implement the pullFromBottom functionality. Then I recently found a fork on GitHub.com which implements it (https://github.com/mysms/ActionBar-PullToRefresh). It allowed me to use the pullFromTop OR pullFromBottom functionality. But I need both to be implemented into my application. Not either/or but both. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem by modifying the source code itself to support what I needed.